# How can I change the frequency and amplitude at the same time?

Tags: arduino, frequency, amplitude

For example, if I need to set the frequency of 100 Hertz, I used the `tone` function to set the frequency using PWM. Now I need to vary the amplitude between 0 - 5 Volts using PWM. Is it possible to use `tone` and `analogWrite` together to fix frequency i.e 100 Hertz and `analogWrite` to change the amplitude?

Let me know if there is any another alternative because I tried the above commands tone and analog write on the same pin , it is not working.

Comment: Hi Dave - can you please post the code that you have already written so that we can help you improve it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that using the `tone` function. Look into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation to get an idea of how a "Frequency" is generated using PWM. This image might be helpful:

[image: PWM waveform]

If you really need to have different voltages, you will either need to add external components on the output pin (a simple voltage divider at least) or you generate the signal using solely `analogWrite`. Be aware that in the latter case timing issues may arise depending on the complexity of your code.

Comment: I am using the tone function because it gives the exact frequency that is 100 hertz and have checked on the oscilloscope at the constant voltage of the battery. At the sametime the analogwrite function for changing the voltage  is not working as I have already changed the frequency.

Answer (score 0):

***Edit***

Have you considered an [digital potentiometer](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10613)? After reading its description, it pretty much matches you need.

> [...] controlling the volume on your stereo [...]

It functions quite like a normal potentiometer and I think it should work for you.

---

***Original post***

The answer is no, because `tone` will output pulses at a set frequency, but then `analogWrite` will ask the pin to output something else. The microcontroller might get "confused" and will probably not do what do you want it to do.

An more mechanical way to get over this problem is to use an potentiometer. It is pretty much a variable resistor that will change its resistance depending on the position of its knob. Why does this work is that no pulses are involved and the only thing you do is to lower the strengh of the signal while not modifying it.

Comment: I have already used the potentiometer to change the voltage , however, I would like to control it digitally using Arduino.I am looking for the option which can serve the same purpose as mechanical potentiometer.

Comment: Yes have used the digital potentiometer , as because I require nearly 100mA , The output current of the wiper is not more than 25mA.

Comment: OpAmp? did you consider that?

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. use analogWrite and throw away the tone function, mimicing the behavior of the tone function;
2. use an external circuit.

The code that can suit the first solution is

```
#define TONE_PERIOD 10 /* Period in milliseconds */
unsigned long lastPulseStart;
byte volume;

void setup()
{
    volume = ...;
    lastPulseChange = millis();
}

void loop()
{
    if (lastPulseStart - millis() < TONE_PERIOD/2)
        analogWrite(pin, volume);
    else if (lastPulseStart - millis() < TONE_PERIOD)
        analogWrite(pin, 0);
    else
        lastPulseStart += TONE_PERIOD;
}
```

For the second solution you can use two pins, then use something to mix the outputs. For instance

- an AND port (tone goes to an input, analogWrite to the other; the and port should be before the filter);
- a buffer with enable input (tone goes to the enable, analogWrite to the line; this can be either before or after the filter);
- if you are using an amplifier and it has an enable pin, use it (of course tone goes to the enable, analogWrite to the line);
- an external ADC (in this case you will use the tone as the voltage reference, the volume should be passed as value for the ADC);
- if you have attached a speaker directly to the output, you can send the analogWrite output to the speaker and put an NMOS on the other pin of the speaker, driven by the tone output.

If you need some schematics just ask..

Comment: My requirement is to fix the frequency at 100 Herts and vary the voltage between 0 to 5 Volts keeping the above-mentioned frequency same.The code which you mention for the first solution , will it serve my purpose if yes then how? could you please elaborate a bit?And for the second solution seems interesting could you please send the schematics or circuit diagram for the same?.I am using 5 Volts external battery and as current requirement is 250mA.

Comment: Well, the tone is a square wave with frequency 100Hz, so every 5ms it will switch from Vdd to GND. If instead of using a fixed voltage you are using a PWM, you just have to turn it on and off. Be careful, though, that analogWrite is outputting a PWM wave, i.e. a square wave of frequency about 500 or 1000 Hz, not a fixed value. You'll have to smooth that out with a filter (but 100Hz is a bit too near). As for the schematics, I need some more time.. Maybe this evening I'll be able to draw something and add it to the answer

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Yes I am aware that as we are not providing the fixed voltage  we are trying to change using PWM , my only doubt is as we have set the frequency at 100 Hertz and again changing the voltage with PWM (500 - 1000hertz) will this affect the constant 100-hertz frequency ?Anyways I would  try to implement the code and will check on the oscilloscope for the same.As I need to have 100 hertz at every voltage between 0 - 5 V .